# Database Mail performance

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

SQL Server Database Mail provides nice built-in features like logging. I would like to use it to send large amounts of email (millions+) really fast (several millions / hour).

Is Database Mail designed for this kind of usage and will I reach the performance I need in production with this solution?

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not. Invest in some listserv software or go through a reputable service provider like [Message Systems](http://www.messagesystems.com/).

BTW what legitimate purpose requires millions of e-mails per hour?

Comment: Notifications to collect your inheritance from a long lost prince.

Comment: Ha ha, apparently I can help out a Nigerian royal family and receive a handsome reward, I just have to give them all my money first...

Comment: A web marketing company which have several clients ? cmon guys does spam requires logging ?

Comment: Sorry, but I worked for an e-mail service provider for 13 years, and we had hundreds of clients. Not once did we ever approach the need to send a million e-mails in an hour - and I know that there is no opt-in list that large. Some of our clients were obeying can-spam rules, but most were probably not. In any case, even at the volume we were doing (2 MM/day, maybe 5 MM/day at peak), we knew Database Mail was not the way to go. You want to send that much junk, pay for something that will scale.

Comment: And if you don't want us to think it's junk, instead of deflecting, explain how your clients have millions of opt-ins & why they need to send at that rate. You don't issue an explanation, of course, but demonstrating that this is a legitimate need and not scumbaggery will likely lead to more people willing to help you.

Comment: There actually are opt-in list that large, such a 20 millions+. On the other side there are clients who want there campaign to be sent in a given amount of time, regardless of spam rules. I may not be aware of the best solutions for this purpose but that is why i'm asking this question here.